# Insert query not working in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, prepared-statement

i want to use the `insert` statement in my query, but the output shows `Unable to connect database`.
I use this form:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="CreateTeam.jsp">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create new team</h2>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Team name" name="name" id="name" required />
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Team description" name="desc" id="desc" required />
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" >Create!</button>
                </form>
```

And my jsp code is:

```
<%
                String name = request.getParameter("name");
                String desc = request.getParameter("desc");

                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                int updateQuery = 0;
                if (name != null && desc != null) {
                    if (name != "" && desc != "") {

                        try {
                            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                            String queryString1 = "insert into teams (name,desc) values (?, ?)";
                            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString1);
                            pstatement.setString(1, name);
                            pstatement.setString(2, desc);
                            updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
                            if (updateQuery != 0) {
                                response.sendRedirect("../AdministrationControlPanel.jsp");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            out.println("Unable to connect to database.");

                        } finally {
                            pstatement.close();
                            connection.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            %>
```

database `test` is running on localhost. I´m modifying it, but i dont know, where is the problem.

Comment: never output a fixed unchanging string as your error message. if you're catching an exception, generally there'll be a useful message in there that explains why the exception was thrown. e.g. why not have mysql TELL you why the connection failed? e.g. `out.println(ex.getMessage())`.

Comment: thanks, this helps me. a forgot, that i dont set autoincrement value to column team_id, which is my first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESC`, in one of your columns, is a MySQL Reserved Keyword. You should escape it using backtick,

```
INSERT INTO teams (name,`desc`) values (?, ?)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

To avoid future problems, it is **much better to avoid keywords** that are MySQL's Reserved keywords.

Comment: I tried the query with other database, where my table has columns team_name and team_d. And the output was same.

Comment: General error, message from server: "Field 'team_id' doesn't have a default value"

I forgot to set the autoincrement value to field team_id

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a keyword of `MySQL` you must quote it.